# Check if TypeElement is a class or an interface

Tags: java

So I am writing an AnnotationProcessor and in the process method you are given a [TypeElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html). I need to check if the TypeElement is an interface or a class. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: -1 This is a very poorly-written question.  Please clarify that you are doing Java type modelling and using a package which allows you to do this.  You don't want to know if the TypeElement is an interface or a class.  You want to know if the data within the TypeElement object represents an interface or class.  Your terse question does not help anyone actually answer it.

Comment: I admit the question could have been written better, but I explained it on your answer, which you disregarded and then proceeded to delete when you realized how wrong you were

Comment: Not well enough, I must say.  I would have to admit that I think a part of the problem is your low reputation.  If it was higher, I might have thought more about your question.  The low reputation seemed to corroborate the idea that it seemed you didn't understand something fundamental about the programming language.  But I definitely didn't disregard your comment - I just misunderstood it.  Also, you should try to avoid inflammatory comments like "when you realized how wrong you were."  We should always strive to be respectful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I completely missed the answer in the JavaDoc.

Its

```
TypeElement.getKind() == ElementKind.INTERFACE
```

or

```
TypeElement.getKind().isInterface()
```